# Use one face's attributes in another

Tags: faces

What is the idiomatic way to make one face the same as another?

Basically, I would like `vertical-border` to be exactly the same as `default`. Preferably, if `default` changes, so does `vertical-border`.

I'm not sure that creating a [face alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Functions.html) is the right thing to do.

- It's not clear that we should be aliasing one face as another.
- By the time the init file is loaded, the vertical border has already rendered, and aliasing does not re-render the vertical border

At the very least, I'd like to have something like `(copy-face 'default 'vertical-border)` that copied all attributes of `default` into `vertical-border`, even if it's a one-time thing and the latter will not change when the former does.

Comment: You want to look-up/Google `customize-face` and the `inherit` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @lawlist said. But you can *ask Emacs* about it, not just Google.

`C-h i m elisp` to visit the Elisp manual, then **`i inherit TAB`**, to look up `inheritance` entries in the index.  Choose **`inheritance, for faces`**.

That takes you to the manual node [Face Attributes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html), which tells you all about how to make one face inherit from others.

Interactively, for your own use, you can do this:

1. `M-x customize-face vertical-border`
2. Change the definition, so that the face just inherits from face `default`.
3. Save your changes.

To make the face inherit from `default`, check the `Inherit` attribute checkbox, and specify `default` as the fact to inherit from.  (`INS` and `DEL` buttons insert a new line/entry and delete the current line/entry, respectively.)

Comment: Thanks, I found "alias" but not "inherit" in the manual. Alas, I realized what I actually wanted as to set the *foreground* of `vertical-border` the same as the *background* of `default`.

Comment: Ah, that you cannot do using `:inherit` - it is separate for each face attribute.